# Curriculum: mention previous work I never started

Tags: cv, curriculum

I am a medical doctor from Europe currently doing my post-graduate speciality in family medicine. I'm applying for a 5-day paid course where the company will select doctors basing their decision solely on CVs (no cover/recommendation letter).

After graduation I attended the national competitive test to get accepted into specialities and was offered a quite prestigious job. I eventually never started to work there since I decided to start family medicine speciality instead (which is entered through a different competitive test).

Is it worth mentioning I got accepted there in this case?

Comment: your title is misleading. Being accepted into something is not "previous work". IMHO, you could mention the result of the test, but be careful not to imply actual work.

Comment: Closely related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/368/is-it-a-good-or-bad-idea-to-list-declined-fellowships-for-a-phd-program-on-one?rq=1

Comment: @FábioDias I actually signed a working contract there. And yes, I obviously didn't get any working experience from that hospital since I never started.